# Why is admob home page and paymets page showing different earning?

Tags: android, admob, payment

When I open admob I see that my earning for last month were 0.02$ and this month 1.05$ but when I go to payments I see that total earnings are just 0.02$. Why, how is that calculated and what happened to 1.05$ ?

**When I open admob :**
[image]

**On payments page:**
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns AdMob policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Remember "Estimated earnings". However unlikely, it is possible that this is an estimation hiccup.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the month the money from this month will go to the payments section, that is because the payment section data is updated monthly.